# SDL2 Mouse Capture

Tags: c++, sdl, x11

Using SDL2 and Vulkan on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I'm trying to hide and capture mouse movement in order to implement mouse movement found commonly in FPS games.

Currently, I initialize SDL using the following functions:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

if (SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE) != 0)
{
    // Deal with error...
}
```

Using `SDL_PollEvent()` and `SDL_MouseMotionEvent`, I am able to mimic the desired camera movement. Although I haven't tested anything on fullscreen mode, in windowed mode, the mouse is hidden and continues to give input even when it passes the borders of the window just like how I want it to be.

However, when I left click with the mouse once and move the mouse afterwards, the mouse appears when it passes the window's borders (yet still gives input).

How can I prevent this from happening? Is there another function other than `SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode()` I could use? Were there any functions I forgot to call during initialization?

Comment: This under the framebuffer console?  X11?  Wayland?

Comment: Currently using X11.

Comment: Could be a bug or some kind of limitation. Have you tried adding `    SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);` as well?

Comment: Tried using it, but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The usual trick is to set the cursor position to the center of your viewport every frame, only when your window is focused, and probably only when mouse-look is active.

Then, when you get a mouse movement event, you can infer the relative movement from how far the cursor moved from the middle. This is not even SDL specific, it is a general algorithm for handling the mouse capture in a generic way. The handy side effect is that it keeps the mouse inside your window without needing help from some fancy OS-specific capturing mechanism.